# Does releasing an object destroy the object?

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory-management

I am new to cocoa-touch, and really unmanaged languages all together.  While I have a firm grasp of the syntax, I am questioning whether I am releasing an object correctly.

I have a view that creates an object,

```
Communication *comm = [[Communication alloc] init];
[comm doSomething];
[comm release];
```

I understand that I have to destroy this object because I am allocating it and it will not auto release.

I call a method on the object that goes out to my server and grabs information.  When the data returns it throws an event which my "message dispatcher" responds to. I do not want to destroy the object until it returns back from the server -- and this is where my confusion is at.

1. If I release this object directly after I make the call, will it destroy the object? (Which I don't want to do.)
2. How do I properly destroy this object after it throws the event with the data I am waiting for?  This would occur within a `DataFinishedLoading` event on my `comm` object.  Should it destroy itself, and is this the right way to do it?

The view calling my object essentially says, create this object, call this method, and go about your merry way.  It doesn't care about what happens after it calls the method -- whether it brings back information or not.  It simply *listens* on a method for any data that may come across at a later time.  I have no reason to hang onto a reference of the object, as I will never use the same instance after I make the call -- that is besides cleaning up after myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `release` only destroys the object if the last retainer released it.

For example, say you allocate your `Communication` object. It is implicitly retained once. Then you retain it five times. You need to release/autorelease the object six times until it gets destroyed (its `dealloc` method is called).

There is an internal counter, the `retainCount`. When you create an object, it is set to `1`. Now every `retain` increases the counter, and every `release` decreases it. `autorelease` also decreases the counter, but not immediately. Once the counter drops to 0 Objective-C knows that the object is no longer needed and destroys it (by calling the object's `dealloc`). **Warning:** do not rely on the `retainCount`, do not even look at it. You should only care that your `alloc/copy/new/retain` calls are balanced with a corresponding `release/autorelease` later on.

Comment: Is it possible to set up my Communication object to auto release itself once its finished?

Comment: @George: You can do `comm = [[[Communication alloc] init] autorelease];`, and once you left the method in which you have made this, the object gets released once (but you don't know when, and don't need to care). You probably mean, *I want the object to vanish once it has finished its work*. That is trickier. Best method is to signal somehow that the work is done (e.g. through a delegate method) and have the creator of the object release it. But an object should not do `[self release];` or something, if that's what you mean. While possible, it's bad style and confusing.

Comment: After I call the object from my view and data is returned at a later date, the Communication object will signal to my app delegate that something has come from my server through a subscription. At that point, the Communication object has done all of its work and will never be needed again -- at least that instance of it. Is it appropriate to release it there?  Or is that the [self release] which you advise against?

Comment: @George: You would do it like this: controller allocates it, with `[[Communication alloc] init];` and stores it in an instance variable. You do not call `release` here. I assume that this controller is the delegate. Your object finishes the work, then calls the delegate/controller. The controller *now* calls `release` on the Communication object (and sets the variable to `nil` as well).

Answer (score 2):

In your above example, `comm` will *likely* be destroyed when you call `release`. It depends on something else retains it during `doSomething`.

If you want to hold onto an object while it does something asynchronously, put it in a retained property. When it informs you that it is done, set the property to `nil` which will release it.